# cant printing the value in the list in python after an if operator

Tags: python-3.x

I try to code a secret word prediction game. I have a list with 9 rows including the key words and the secret word. Secret word is in the first row. I wrote the code below but whatever I input as a "guess" it returns me "found the secret and the secret word (the first value of the list).

```
secret1 = open("keywordlist.txt", "r")
list1= (keywordlist.readlines())

  
gid=input("enter the game id: ")
if gid:=1:
    print("category is", (list1[8]))
    guess=input("guess the secret: ")
    if guess := list1[0]:
        print("found the secret", (list1[0]))
    elif guess==list1[1]:
        print("found a hint", (guess))
```

I wrote the code below but whatever I input as a "guess" it returns me "found the secret and the key word.
I want to do that my code check the input value and if it equals to first value of the list, it prints found the secret row.
If it equals to other values of the list, it prints the found a hint row.

Comment: `if guess := list1[0]:` uses the Walrus-operator, and sets the variable `guess` as `list1[0]` if it is Truthy. If the variable is Truthy, then the if-statement is True as well.

Comment: Explained differently: Your if-statement `if guess := list1[0]:` is always `True` because the part `guess :=` is not an evaluation, it is an assignment, so the real if-statement that your code is evaluating is: `if list1[0]:`

Comment: same problem here: `if gid:=1:`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code as well.

Firstly, it should be `secret1.readlines()`

`if gid:=1:` should be `gid==1:` because you are checking if it's equal to

You mentioned that you want to check if the input is the same as first element in list, this portion is correct but note the operator `!=`. Next, you want to print "found a hint" if it's NOT the same as first element BUT is within the list, so use `elif guess in list:`. If not in list at all, goes to `else:`

```
if guess != list1[0]:
   print("found the secret", (list1[0]))
elif guess in list:
   print("found a hint", (guess))
else:
   print("not within the list")
```

Please note, because I don't have your keywordlist.txt, this only works if your list contain the EXACT keyword, and not a substring of the keyword. A different application is required if it isn't this condition.